# Nuxt 3 return dynamic JSON file from api call

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

So I have a few json files under my assets folder. I want to be able to dynamiclly call these files. I don't know if I'm doing it right but the way I thought of doing it is to call an api so that the api returns the json.

So for example this is in a component of mine:

```
const {data} = await useFetch('/api/states', {
        query: {file: newVal}
    })
```

this is in my server/api/states:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const baseUrl = process.env.API_BASE_URL
    const query = getQuery(event)
    const file = query.file

    try{
        const data: any = await $fetch(`/assets/countries/country-states/${file}.json`)
        return data
    } catch (error){
        return error
    }
})
```

This is what I'm getting back: `"Page not found: /assets/countries/country-states/state.json"`

Comment: can you give some data of your those json files?